# Where to find data from phpldapadmin in ldapserver in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap, phpldapadmin

I am using ldap server in Ubuntu. From phpldapadmin I created a new entry. In ldap server I can see all my created data when i use command `$ ldapsearch -x`:

```
# leja, example, people, ldap.com
dn: cn=leja,cn=example,ou=people,dc=ldap,dc=com
givenName: Leja
gidNumber: 500
homeDirectory: /home/users/leja
sn: Bin
loginShell: /bin/sh
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
uidNumber: 1001
uid: leja
cn: leja
```

But can't find the location where this data is stored in Ubuntu in ldap server. As I understand it should be `*.ldif` file.

I want that my ldap server allow users change their own `'userPassword'` attribute. So I need to modify users data.

Can you help me where can I find the data?

Answer (score 0):

Don't expect OpenLDAP (or any other LDAP server for that matter) to store entries as LDIF files on your disk.  LDAP servers use a database backend (often embedded) to store entries.  You're not supposed to access the database other than through the LDAP protocol, though.

[LDIF](http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-2849.txt) is just a commonly used file format for external representation of directory entries used by tools like ldapsearch, ldapmodify, etc.  Also, LDIF files are used to initialize a directory server, so don't be surprised if you find LDIF files on your disk.  They are often used to backup and restore configuration (and user) data.

If you want users to change their own password, you'll have to grant write access to the password attribute to the authenticated user via access control statements in the [slapd configuration file](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconfig.html).  [Read about access control](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html), and look at the sample configuration at the end of the slapdconfig document.